# The "open in paw" button is not working in mashape

Tags: paw-app

I'm trying out APIs on marketplace / mashape and there is an "Open in Paw" button. That bring up a dialog offering to get Paw or, if already installed to open in Paw.
I do have Paw, it's open and when I click on "Open in Paw" it does bring Paw to the foreground, but nothing is imported. I've tried installing all the importer extensions I could find, I've tried "paste and import", but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Unfortunately, Mashape and us (Paw) are not supporting this feature very much anymore. As for us at Paw, we've heavily moved into supporting API description formats (Swagger/OAI and RAML mostly) though open source projects to allow conversion and importing. If you're curious you can checkout https://console.rest which should be officially released soon. In anyway, sorry I don't think we will be supporting this button in Mashape much :(

Comment: OK thanks for the answer Micha. I'll certainly look into console.rest.